# Creating list from feature and modifying library content types using web services?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online

I am creating a CRM online plugin using the SharePoint web services. Both of these sites are hosted in Office 365, so I am stuck with SharePoint web services. I am trying to create new asset libraries using an existing template. I am calling AddListFromFeature, which will create the library, but it is not populated with anything from the template. If I go inside SharePoint and create a new library using the template, it works great.

If anyone knows any magic surrounding AddListFromFeature, I would love to hear it.

Anyway, because AddListFromFeature isn't working right, I am trying to manually add content types to the new library I have created. The content types exist already and I just want to associate them with the libraries I am creating. I am experimenting with UpdateListItems, but I'm not getting very far. Is this possible to do with web services?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your existing template a custom one?

Comment: Yes it is custom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the ApplyContentTypeToList operation. UpdateListItems is used to update individual items in the list, not the list itself.